# Linkage error:Loader Constraint violation: previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/Type Info"

Tags: grails-2.0, linkageerror

I am using `java1.6,grails 2.0`. I want to process Docx documents.For this i have added jars  `poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar,ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar.`
But in code line `this.document = new XWPFDocument(buffInputStream);` 
i got below error

```
Class    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Message    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions
```

I am trying to add jars either  `xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar or xbean-2.1.0.jar.`

I am getting below error

```
 | Error Fatal error during compilation
     org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java .lang.LinkageError: loader
     constraint violation: loader (instance of bootloader)
 previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/Type Info" (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

If i  verify my Jre System Library, rt.jar contains this TypeInfo class. how
 to solve this problem? Please advice. Thank you.

Hi,
I have tried removing library and used `jarscan` to search this class. But i didn't find any where. Please help out to figure out how else i can find where is this class and how to resolve this

Comment: Hi, is there any issue in the question? why i am not getting any response? please help me out as i struck on how to continue on this issue? Thank you

Comment: I posted my answer below. Is it acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with the JMX MBeanServer class. Groovy was loading one of them with its classloader and so was the JVM.
In your case it sounds like the TypeInfo class exists in rt.jar just fine, but another class loader loads it from that jar (or another jar) again.
Running the JRE with "-verbose:class" showed that double load behavior. Then I moved the offending jar out of my classpath and it worked just fine with the one loaded by Groovy.

I would recommend moving rt.jar out of your classpath, or if you need other classes inside of rt.jar try unjaring and rejaring it without the Type class. That way the classloaders will be forced to use the ones in xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar or xbean-2.1.0.jar.